# Matplotlib is overlapping scales on x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting in a loop and somehow all plots show overlapping scales on both axes.
No matter if printed or saved to a file.

```
plt.clf()
plt.title(label)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_facecolor('silver')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)
plt.plot(np.arange(start-151, end), low.values[start-150:])
plt.plot(np.arange(start-151, end), high.values[start-150:])
plt.plot(idx, p, c='r')
plt.scatter(idx[-1], p[-1], c='green')
now = datetime.now()
plt.savefig(f'has_pattern_{now}{m}.jpg')
```

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: You should call `plt.axes()` only once, before the start of the loop.

Comment: Note that your post is missing reproducible code.

Comment: @JohanC that's it! thanks! do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: The code in your post doesn't even include a loop. I would prefer to close the question, as it is just a misunderstanding of seldom-used matplotlib functionality. Normally, you would have `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` once, at the start of the code.